# Promtail does not sent logs after restarting the host

Tags: monitoring, grafana, logging

I have a Loki server that receives logs from other servers. The logs from containers have no problem(grafana/loki-docker-driver). However, other logs(Promtail) from log files are not updated after each restart. To fix this, I SSH into the server and restart Promtail and then it start working again even though it was started before.

This is my Promtail configuration:

```
server:
http_listen_port: 0
grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: /var/promtail/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://example.com:3100/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:
- job_name: example
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: example
      __path__: /var/log/syslog
      server: development
```

This is the default systemd unit configuration for Promtail on my server(Ubuntu22.04).

```
[Unit]
Description=Promtail service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=promtail
ExecStart=/usr/bin/promtail -config.file /etc/promtail/config.yml
# Give a reasonable amount of time for promtail to start up/shut down
TimeoutSec = 60
Restart = on-failure
RestartSec = 2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My questions are why Promtail does not send logs automatically? and how to configure it to do that after each host restart?

Comment: How are you running promtail? Are you running it as a systemd unit?

Comment: @Colwin, Yes, I updated the question with the systemd unit config file. Promtail will add this unit by default when I install it on Ubuntu.

Comment: What's the version of systemd that you are running Check out these issues -> https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/8163
https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/2792

They have a couple workarounds you can try.

Comment: It's 245, I read that post tnx. But my problem is not with journal and systemd logs. It's happening Promtail itself. I can not receive Apache, database, ... . logs too.